# get the largest number from url in php?

Tags: php

On my website I have my pages in this format:

```
www.mysite.com/45.php
www.mysite.com/81.php
www.mysite.com/58.php
www.mysite.com/415.php
```

I have the numbers in order. How can I get the largest number which is in this case 415 and store it in a var. I tried this:

```
<?php
for ($urlCheck = 1000000; ; $urlCheck--){
    if (file_exists()){
        echo "true";
        break;
        }

    }

?>
```

but I am not sure how I get this thing to work.

Comment: yes, it starts at 1 and I want to find what is the last or the largest number is ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

// a url looks like: http://www.mysite.com
// a path looks like: /home/vhosts/www.mysite.com/public

`$path = getcwd(); // get current path (needs to be where 45.php etc is)
    chdir($path);     // go there
    $files = scandir('.'); // we are looking in the current directory 
    natsort($files); 
    $largest = intval(end($files)); // sample value: "415" 
    $filename = end($files);
// if you just want the number from a filename:
    $number=preg_replace('/[^\d]/','',$filename);`

Answer (score 3):

You will have to save the "current largest number" somewhere when you add a page, otherwise (with any solutions that try to find it out on the spot) the performance is going to be atrocious.

For a slow implementation that's still less slow than others you may come up with, you can use this:

```
$files = scandir('.'); // assume we are looking in the current directory
natsort($files);
$largest = intval(end($files)); // sample value: "415"
```

Comment: @user1200640: Probably because you have not supplied the correct path to `scandir`.

Comment: the largest number is what I want to get, yet it is something I do not know, so how can I pass it to the parameter ?

Comment: @user1200640: You don't need to pass it because that parameter is something totally unrelated. Please read the manual on `scandir` before asking further questions.

Comment: @user1200640: Neither of the above. Please read the manual (e.g. what a [path](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_%28computing%29#Unix_style) is), I cannot keep answering such basic questions.